# is it correct using pre-marinated

Tags: word-usage

I argue that if a person refers to marinated meat, as pre-marinated, the use of pre-   is not necessary   am I correct or incorrect?

Comment: You can marinate leftovers, if you want to make something else or of them. So I think it's more a matter of emphasis than redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Simply saying marinated is alway correct.  Adding "pre-" may help define context in some situations.  Here are some examples that sound more clear one way or the other:

> I bought meat for the BBQ tonight that was pre-marinated.
>
> I maninated the meat this morning.
>
> I maninated the meat for four hours.  (Note that pre-marinated would not work in this example.)